# Typescript, promises and multiples response types

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

Trying to learn some Angular 4, and got this problem.

I have a REST Server (Spring Boot), that has a endpoint to login the user, that will respond with a JWT token in the header, if the login was successfully, otherwise, respond with a 401 or 500 (if something goes wrong).

So, to check the login, I used the following code (in a service):

```
export const TOKEN_NAME = 'jwt_token';
const AUTH_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';
const AUTH_PREFIX = 'Bearer';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> | Promise<never> 
  {
    const credentials = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };

    const req = this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/login`, credentials, { headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' });
    return req.toPromise()
      .then(r => this.processLoginResponse(r))
      .catch(e => this.handleLoginError(e));
  }

  private processLoginResponse(res: HttpResponseBase): boolean {
    if (res.header.has(AUTH_HEADER_KEY)) {
      const authorizationHeaderValue = res.headers.get(AUTH_HEADER_KEY);

      const regex = new RegExp(`^${AUTH_PREFIX} (.*)`);
      const m = regex.exec(authorizationHeaderValue);

      if (m !== undefined && m.length === 2) {
        // TODO: store the token on localstorage
        return true
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  private handleLoginError(error: HttpErrorResponse): boolean | Promise<never> {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      return false;

    } else if (error.status === 403) {
      // bad request
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Bad request custom message'));

    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Something goes wrong!'));
    }
  }
}
```

So, in my `AuthService`, the `login` method can return a boolean (promise) or a error.

Then, in my component, if I try to use the following code:

`const loginResult = this.authService.login('john_smith', 'secret123').then(r => { console.log(r); });`

I got a error, with the following content:

`TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<TResult1 = boolean, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: boolean) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...' has no compatible call signatures.`.

No ideia how to correct this.

Comment: Is this just a typo in the question... `Promisse<boolean>` (double-s)?

Comment: ops. sorry. it's a typo! correcting right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Promise<boolean>` is a a promise that, when resolved, calls its callbacks with a `boolean` parameter.

A `Promise<never>` is a promise that, when resolved, calls its callbacks with a `never` parameter.  But there are no `never` values, so a `Promise<never>` can never be resolved.

Okay, so, you declare that `login()` returns a `Promise<boolean> | Promise<never>`.  That means it returns *either* a `Promise<boolean>` or a `Promise<never>`.  Now, if you hand one of those to me, when I call `then()` on it, what type of parameter can I pass to it?  Well, if it's a `Promise<boolean>` I can hand you a `boolean`.  But if it's a `Promise<never>` I can only hand you a `never`.  But I don't know which one it is, because you handed me something which can be *either* of them.  So the only thing I can safely do is pass you something that's *both* a `boolean` and a `never`.  So that's just a `never`.  Oops, that's not what you want.

The specific error you got is because [TypeScript won't allow you to call a method on a union of types where the method signatures differ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-312070139).  But even if you resolve that error the only thing safe for you to pass to `then()` is a `never` type.  That can't be what you intend.

---

Let's back up.

Do you want `login()` to return a `Promise<boolean>` *or* a `Promise<never>`?  Or do you want it to return a `Promise<boolean | never>`?  Meaning, a promise that, when resolved, calls its callbacks with *either* a `boolean` or a `never`.  In other words, a promise that calls its callbacks with a `boolean` or never calls its callbacks.  In other words, a `Promise<boolean>`.  If you change the return type of `login()` to `Promise<boolean>`, then the promise, if it gets resolved, will receive a `boolean`.  This allows you to call `then()` on it:

```
const loginResult = this.authService.login('john_smith', 'secret123').then(r => { console.log(r); }); // okay
```

Is that better?  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I like that the `login` function return a `Promise<boolean>` or a error that I can treat. So, I changed the return type of  `login` method to `Promise<boolean>` (only), and the `handleLoginError` return type to `boolean | Error ` (used `return new Error`). Now, I got no compiler error, but can't catch the errors (`...then(r => { console.log(r); }).catch(e => { console.error(e); });`) <-- console.error never called even when the backend response is different than OK or invalid login (200, 203, or 401)

Comment: That seems like a separate question.  Your runtime code always had this problem no matter what you declared the `login()` return type to be.

Comment: I don't have a great answer for this second question, unfortunately.  Angular's `Observable` gets turned into a `Promise` via rxjs and I don't know where along the line the error gets trapped.  Best answered by an angular/rxjs expert, which I'm not.  Good luck!

Comment: tks @jcalz. I already resolved all the problems. If anybody is interested in the code, I posted in the following link: https://gist.github.com/tobecwb/9448f9fb20e0a4362a4290b7e34c3869

Comment: this is how typescript should be taught LOL... Using scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

`Promise<never>` - I think this is what's causing it. "never" is a special TypeScript type to mark method that **never returns at all** - it's either throws an exception or shuts down the whole "machine" - nodejs runtime, for example. If you want to mark the method that **does not return value** then you need to do `Promise<void>`.

Comment: give-me the same error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResul...' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: Where exactly compiler points out? You need to change **all** signatures `Promise<never>` to `Promise<void>`. Also, what is your tsc version?

Comment: already changed the signature in all functions (in `AuthService`, on functions `login` and `handleLoginErrror`). The error occur on component that use the service (`this.authService.login('foo', 'bar').then(r => { console.log(r); });` tsc version is 2.4.1

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov: examine this code: `declare const x: Promise<number> | Promise<boolean>; x.then(x => console.log(x));`.  The problem is that you are trying to call a [union of function types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-312070139) and TypeScript won't let you do that.

Comment: @jcalz - true. Although I don't see why declare `Promise<never>` at all.